# sdkman does not provide more java candidates on Apple Silicon M1

Tags: apple-m1, sdkman

I'm trying to install a different version of java amzn on macOS Apple Silicon M1 but it's no other candidate available than the listed ones:

[image]

Would it be possible to get extra candidates?

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Ask your vendor of choice to publish their product via SDKMAN using simple REST API or Gradle/Maven plugin.

To refresh the list of products, run the [`update`](https://sdkman.io/usage#update) command.

```sh
sdk update
```

You asked:

> install a different version of java amzn on macOS Apple Silicon

I see Amazon offering four releases of [Corretto](https://aws.amazon.com/corretto/) for Macs with Apple Silicon:

- 18
- 18.0.1
- 17.0.3.6.1
- 17.0.2.8.1

## Details

As I understand it, the way SDKMAN works is that a vendor chooses to publish their releases via that avenue. If you want a product from a vendor not currently listed, ask that vendor to make their product available via SDKMAN.

To quote the SDKMAN web site:

> SDKMAN! is unique in that it empowers SDK Vendors to publish their candidate releases on our platform. We provide a secure API that can be used to manage all aspects of a release on SDKMAN!. Such aspects include Releasing a new version, setting an existing version as Default (Stable) and Announcing the release on the SDKMAN! CLI broadcast and Twitter feed.

The process seems quite simple. See the [*Vendors*](https://sdkman.io/vendors) page of the SDKMAN web site.

- SDKMAN makes available a JSON REST API by which a vendor supplies their release information.
- If the vendor prefers not to mess with `cURL` or `HttpClient`, they may alternatively choose to use the plugins for [Gradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle) or [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) as the way to publish their new build.

As of 2022-04, the list of product offerings on SDKMAN for the [Java platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(software_platform)) on [Macs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh) with [Apple Silicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_silicon) has grown in just these last two months. When I run `sdk list java`, I get eight vendors offering various products that include:

- Current version [18.0.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_18)
- All three [LTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_support) versions ([8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_8), [11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_11), [17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_17))
- Early-access version of Java [19](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_19).

```
================================================================================
Available Java Versions for macOS ARM 64bit
================================================================================
 Vendor        | Use | Version      | Dist    | Status     | Identifier
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Corretto      |     | 18           | amzn    |            | 18-amzn             
               | >>> | 18.0.1       | amzn    | installed  | 18.0.1-amzn         
               |     | 17.0.3.6.1   | amzn    |            | 17.0.3.6.1-amzn     
               |     | 17.0.2.8.1   | amzn    |            | 17.0.2.8.1-amzn     
 Java.net      |     | 19.ea.19     | open    |            | 19.ea.19-open       
               |     | 19.ea.18     | open    |            | 19.ea.18-open       
               |     | 19.ea.5.lm   | open    |            | 19.ea.5.lm-open     
               |     | 18           | open    |            | 18-open             
               |     | 18.0.1       | open    |            | 18.0.1-open         
               |     | 17.0.2       | open    |            | 17.0.2-open         
 Liberica      |     | 18.fx        | librca  |            | 18.fx-librca        
               |     | 18.0.1.fx    | librca  |            | 18.0.1.fx-librca    
               |     | 18.0.1       | librca  |            | 18.0.1-librca       
               |     | 18           | librca  |            | 18-librca           
               |     | 17.0.3.fx    | librca  |            | 17.0.3.fx-librca    
               |     | 17.0.3       | librca  |            | 17.0.3-librca       
               |     | 17.0.2.fx    | librca  |            | 17.0.2.fx-librca    
               |     | 17.0.2       | librca  |            | 17.0.2-librca       
               |     | 11.0.15      | librca  |            | 11.0.15-librca      
               |     | 11.0.14      | librca  |            | 11.0.14-librca      
               |     | 8.0.332      | librca  |            | 8.0.332-librca      
               |     | 8.0.322      | librca  |            | 8.0.322-librca      
 Microsoft     |     | 17.0.2       | ms      |            | 17.0.2-ms           
               |     | 11.0.14      | ms      |            | 11.0.14-ms          
 Oracle        |     | 18.0.1       | oracle  |            | 18.0.1-oracle       
               |     | 18           | oracle  |            | 18-oracle           
               |     | 17.0.3       | oracle  |            | 17.0.3-oracle       
               |     | 17.0.2       | oracle  |            | 17.0.2-oracle       
 SapMachine    |     | 18           | sapmchn |            | 18-sapmchn          
               |     | 18.0.1       | sapmchn |            | 18.0.1-sapmchn      
               |     | 17.0.2       | sapmchn |            | 17.0.2-sapmchn      
 Temurin       |     | 18           | tem     |            | 18-tem              
               |     | 17.0.2       | tem     |            | 17.0.2-tem          
 Zulu          |     | 18           | zulu    |            | 18-zulu             
               |     | 18.fx        | zulu    |            | 18.fx-zulu          
               |     | 17.0.3       | zulu    |            | 17.0.3-zulu         
               |     | 17.0.2       | zulu    |            | 17.0.2-zulu         
               |     | 17.0.2.fx    | zulu    |            | 17.0.2.fx-zulu      
               |     | 11.0.15      | zulu    |            | 11.0.15-zulu        
               |     | 11.0.14      | zulu    |            | 11.0.14-zulu        
               |     | 8.0.332      | zulu    |            | 8.0.332-zulu        
               |     | 8.0.322      | zulu    |            | 8.0.322-zulu        
================================================================================
```